# merge two strings in one string

Tags: string, julia

I am new in julia programming and I don't know if what I wrote is right.

The question is that I have two strings, the first is "dog" the second is "fish", so the merge of these strings should be done one character by one character like this : "dfoigsh".

I am trying to write code to merge two strings but it doesn't work:

```
str1 = "fuad"
str2 = "hesen"
result = ""
str = ""
merge = str1 * str2

if length(str1)>length(str2)
str= str1
else str=str2
end

for i = 1:length(merge)
        result[i]=str1[i] #fuad , hesenkl, result = fhueasdenkl
        result[j+1]=str2[j]
        j=j+1
        i=i+1
end
println(result)
println(str)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping, its usefull that i  did not found much excercis for julia. what i need its not just merge them. its exactly like that. str1 = asdfg , str2 = qw so that result of merge is aqswdfg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in Julia strings are immutable. Therefore in order to merge them you exactly have to use `*` operator as you did:

```
julia> str1 = "fuad"
"fuad"

julia> str2 = "hesen"
"hesen"

julia> merge = str1 * str2
"fuadhesen"
```

If you want to make an exercise with iterating over strings you could create a `Vector` of characters contained in `str1` and `str2` and then convert it to a `String` using `join` for example like this:

```
julia> res = Char[]
0-element Array{Char,1}

julia> for c in str1
           push!(res, c)
       end

julia> res
4-element Array{Char,1}:
 'f'
 'u'
 'a'
 'd'

julia> for c in str2
           push!(res, c)
       end

julia> res
9-element Array{Char,1}:
 'f'
 'u'
 'a'
 'd'
 'h'
 'e'
 's'
 'e'
 'n'

julia> join(res)
"fuadhesen"
```

Is this what you wanted?

**EDIT** Here is a merge example:

```
julia> str1 = "fuad"
"fuad"

julia> str2 = "hesen"
"hesen"

julia> str1, str2 = "fuad", "hesen"
("fuad", "hesen")

julia> c1, c2 = collect(str1), collect(str2)
(['f', 'u', 'a', 'd'], ['h', 'e', 's', 'e', 'n'])

julia> res = Char[]
0-element Array{Char,1}

julia> for i in 1:max(length(c1), length(c2))
           i > length(c1) || push!(res, c1[i])
           i > length(c2) || push!(res, c2[i])
       end

julia> res
9-element Array{Char,1}:
 'f'
 'h'
 'u'
 'e'
 'a'
 's'
 'd'
 'e'
 'n'

julia> join(res)
"fhueasden"
```

Comment: It appears that he wants to merge the strings, not concatenate them.

Comment: In the accepted solution you will not have `n` at the end of the string so probably you have to append the end of longer string (above common part) to its output.

Comment: And how I can do that ?

Comment: I have added an example how you can do it relatively simply (this is not a most efficient way; I have chosen an approach that should be easy to follow) in my response.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues with your code. @BogumilKaminski has shown how you can concatenate strings in general, but you asked if what you "wrote is right", so I'll point out some problems.

```
str1 = "fuad"
str2 = "hesen"
result = ""
str = ""
merge = str1 * str2
```

As mentioned, strings are immutable, that means once you have made one you cannot change it, only make a new one. Above, you are initializing `result` to be an empty string--that won't work, you cannot update that. You're also initializing `str`, but that makes no sense either, because below you are reassigning it, so the initialization was wasted anyway. Notice also that `str1` and `str2` are of different lengths, which is a problem.

```
if str1>str2
str= str1
else str=str2
end
```

Here, you are comparing `str1` and `str2` with a `>`. I'm not sure what you are going for. This is a lexical comparison, so you are ordering them alphabetically. Is that what you wanted? Or did you want to compare their lengths? In that case you should write `length(str1) > length(str2)`. If you actually wanted alphabetical comparison, you can instead write `str = max(str1, str2)`.

```
for i = 1:merge
        result[i]=str1[i]
        result[j+1]=str2[j]
        j=j+1
        i=i+1
end
```

This won't work, for four reasons, or five reasons, depending on how you count.

- `1:merge` makes no sense, since `merge` is a string. You cannot count from 1 to "fuadhesen". (Also, you cannot use strings or characters as indices into an array.) I guess you meant `for i = 1:length(merge)`, is that right?
- Strings are immutable, so you cannot mutate/update them like this anyway.
- Even if strings *were* mutable, you only pre-allocated empty strings, so writing `result[i] = str1[i]` would not be allowed because `result` is empty and would not have space to accept any characters anyway. If strings were mutable you would have to use `push!`.
- The variable `j` just shows up in your loop without any initial value. Where did that come from?

**Edit:** BTW, here is a partial solution to your question of merging. You can use the `zip` function, which 'zips' two (or more) iterators together like a zipper. Then, use the `append!` function which adds multiple elements to the end of your collection (for single characters you can use `push!`). In the end, creates a string with `join`:

```
cstr = Char[]  # initialize empty vector of Characters
for c in zip(str1, str2)  # iterate over zipped strings
    append!(cstr, c)  # append them onto your empty array
end
# push!(cstr, last(str2))  # str1 and str2 are different lengths, if you want last 'n' to join you can uncomment this line.
str = join(cstr)  # collect into string
```

Please make sure that you read the documentation for strings, https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/  Also look up the docs for `push!`, `append!`, `zip` and `join`. By just copying the code you won't learn much.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation +1. It was unclear for me what "merge" meant in the question. @Fuad Sami - just note that in `zip` Julia will iterate till it hits the end of either of the strings, so that if they have an unequal length then the overlong part of the longer string will not get into the `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Other replies have done a good job of explaining strings and pointing to more resources for learning, so I'll skip that bit and just suggest a solution.

```
result = string(Iterators.flatten(zip(str1, str2))...)
```

Note however that this will truncate the longest string to match the shortest.

Comment: and what if i need to use just if or for loops, with no push or zip or collect, can we do that